# Javascript collision detection generating score more than what it should be

Tags: javascript, collision-detection

I am creating a simple javascript game where a paddle needs to catch raining blocks. When there is a collision, score should increase by 1, but in my case, the score increases by 12.

I am quite sure that there is collision detection, because the block disappears when it touches the paddle and I have a console.log to show me that there is a collision.

My collision detection code

```html
var spawnRate = 1500;
    var spawnRateOfDescent = 2;
    var lastSpawn = -10;
    var objects = [];
    var startTime = Date.now();
    var score =0;

    function spawnRandomObject() {
    
        var t;

        if (Math.random() < 0.50) 
        {
            t = "red";
        } 
        else 
        {
            t = "blue";
        }
   
        var object = {      
            type: t, 
            x: Math.random() * (canvas.width - 30) + 15,
            y: 100,
            r: 8,
            status: 1 
        }
         
       objects.push(object);
    }


    function animate() 
    {
        var time = Date.now();    
        if (time > (lastSpawn + spawnRate)) {
            lastSpawn = time;
            spawnRandomObject();
        }

        var paddleLeft=paddleX;
        var paddleRight=paddleX+paddleWidth;
        var paddleTop=paddleY;
        var paddleBottom=paddleY+paddleHeight;
      
        for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) 
        {

            var object = objects[i];
            object.y += spawnRateOfDescent;

            if (object.status == 1){ //only draw the ball if the status is 1
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(object.x, object.y, object.r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fillStyle = object.type;
            ctx.fill();
            }

            var objectTop=object.y-object.r;
            var objectBottom=object.y+object.r;
            var objectLeft=object.x-object.r;
            var objectRight=object.x+object.r;

            
            if (objectRight>paddleX && objectLeft<paddleX+paddleWidth && objectBottom>paddleY && objectTop<paddleY+paddleHeight)
            {
                object.status = 0; 
                console.log("collision");
                score = score +1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following piece of code, you're adding the score:

```
            if (objectRight>paddleX && objectLeft<paddleX+paddleWidth && objectBottom>paddleY && objectTop<paddleY+paddleHeight)
            {
                object.status = 0; 
                console.log("collision");
                score = score +1;
            }
```

I see you're setting the `status` of the object to 0. You could use this in the condition:

```
            if (objectRight>paddleX && objectLeft<paddleX+paddleWidth && objectBottom>paddleY && objectTop<paddleY+paddleHeight && object.status === 1)
            {
                object.status = 0; 
                console.log("collision");
                score++;
            }
```

Keep in mind that you're not deleting the object from the array.

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution is working perfectly.